# Не получается скрыть элементы с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Не получается скрыть иконки ссылок `.links a img` в версии сайта для слабовидящих. Задумка была, что при открытии версии для слабовидящих картинки скрываются, а вместо них показываются текстовые ссылки. В локальной версии все работает, а как только загружаю в сеть то перестает. Ошибок в консоли не показывает, если ввожу код через консоль он срабатывает. Есть подозрение, что картинки не успевают загрузиться до применения кода к ним, ведь весь остальной код работает. 
Пробовал сделать с помощью события onload - картинки при загрузке появляются, затем скрываются, но хотелось бы, чтобы они изначально не показывались

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function loadform() {
    $("<button style='float:right'  onclick='$.removeCookie(\"openspec\", { path: \"/\" });location.reload();'>Закрыть версию для слабовидящих</button>").insertBefore("body");
    $("body").before("<iframe width='100%' height='110'  style='border: none' src='specver/spec.html'></iframe>");

    //Добавлено:
    //    спрятать изображения блока ссылок, поиск, кнопку спецверсии
    $(" .links a img, .search-form, .header-links button").hide();

    //    показать ссылки текстом вместо изображений
    $(".links .texthide").css("display", "flex");

    //    увеличенный шрифт по умолчанию
    $("body p, .header-links, footer a, .navigation a").css("font-size", "150%");
    $("h2").css("font-size", "250%");
    $(".menu > li span, .sub-menu a").css("font-size", "130%");
    $(".menu > li > a").css("font-size", "160%");
    $("body *").css("font-family", "Arial");
  };

  $('.spec').click(function(e) {

    if (!$.cookie('openspec')) {
      $.cookie('openspec', 1, {
        path: '/'
      });
      $("body *").css("background", "#fff");
      $("body *").css("color", "#000");
      $("img").css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");
      loadform();
    }
  });

  if ($.cookie('openspec') == 1)
    loadform();
});
```

Порядок подключения скриптов ниже (последний файл с чистым JS для открытия меню)

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>сайт</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/media.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="specver/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="specver/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="specver/js/specver.js"></script>
  <script async src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/ao.png" alt="Описание картинки" /><span class="texthide">текст</span></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/sc.png" alt="Описание картинки" /><span class="texthide">текст</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pr.png" alt="Описание картинки" /><span class="texthide">текст</span></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pu.png" alt="Описание картинки" /><span class="texthide">текст</span></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: если надо чтобы изначально не показывались, добавляйте к body класс на серверной стороне, чтоб работает версия для слабовидящих, и в css скрывайте их. Если будет делать скриптом, то они так и будут мелькать при загрузке.

Comment: то есть вообще ваша задача решается просто переопределением `display:none` для картинок и текста в зависимости от текущей версии, js тут и не нужен. причем это касается и размеров шрифтов и всего что вы делаете в js.

Comment: соглашусь с предыдущим ответом, но если вы все же захотите делать подобным образом как сделано у вас, можете наоборот ставить картинкам изначально display: none, а потом на событие onload делать им .show() если нужно.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Искал где почитать про способы создания и как вообще правильно оформить версию для слабовидящих, но ничего внятного не нашел, может кто сможет поделиться ссылкой или названием подходящей литературы